# SQL like statement excluding too much

Tags: sql, sql-like

I'm having some trouble with a sql LIKE statement:

Let's say I have three records in my table named articles. The table has a column named content:

```
content
-------
lorem ipsum hey jippi lorem ipsum ipusm lorum
yippi
lorem ipsum heyyippikayay lorem ipsum
```

The following statement returns all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE content LIKE '%jippi%';
```

But how can I match content1 and content2.

If I go:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE content LIKE 'jippi%';
```

I will only get content2. This query excludes content1 because it is preceded by 'hey...', but my intention was to exclude records where the string 'yippi' is only found as a part of a word, as in content3. However, if 'yippi' is found in the beginning of a string as in 'yippiyay' I want to return this row.

Thus: I need an sql like statement that only returns records where I find my exact searchterm OR where there are words starting with the searchterm, i.e. 'yippi' or 'yippiyay'.

Comment: Content 2 is `yippi`, but `%jippi%` is matching it?

Comment: Try this `LIKE '% yippi%'`, put a space after first '%'

Comment: Yes @DominicZukiewicz, that's correct.

Comment: @user1009453: What DB platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE content LIKE 'jippi%' or content like '% jippi%';
```

But this will work only if you have a single space between the words.
The solution with:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE content LIKE '%ippi';
```

is good but will not catch words like jippido or similar, which starts with jippi.

Comment: yep, using single space is probably the only way. Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE content LIKE '%ippi';
```

I still don't understand the purpose of it but it does work...

Comment: Maybe, I didn't express myself very well, but the purpose is quite simple. I need to return all records where the string (just an example) 'yippi' is found, whether or not it is preceded by any words or not. But I don't want to return rows where the string is found (by chance) as a part of a string ie, 'yayippi', unless 'yippi' comes first in the string, ie 'yippikayay'